# Can we handle authentication with slack and google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, slack, slack-api

So lets say i have a meeting/event in which i want only those users which are in my workspace to be able to attend the meeting.

So i want to devise a way which connects their slack and google calendar or google meet or any other application.

When they try to access that event meeting link ( if its happening from google calendar/meet or any other app ), slack should authenticate them. so if they are present in my workspace they should be given access otherwise no

Update:-

**The users are not part of organization so they all will be using their personal email.**

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can sync the Slack and Google Calendar, to do this:

**1.) Add the Google Calendar app to Slack.**

---

[image]

**2.) Connect your Google Calendar to Slack.**

---

[image]

For more details refer to this link: [Google Calendar for Slack](https://slack.com/help/articles/206329808-Google-Calendar-for-Slack#fix-calendar-syncing-issues)

### About the Access:

Take note **Google Calendar** and **Google Meet** are two different Google Apps. As for those who are able to access the meeting link it has nothing to do with the Google Calendar. You can set the Google Meet Settings reference in your Google Admin Console: [image]

- [Google Meet settings reference for admins](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7304109?hl=en)

---

**Update:**

> i have a question the users who are going to join this meeting are not from my organization, they can anyone but they should be someone from my slack workspace.

Unfortunately there is no way you can do it since technically as a default anyone with the Google Meet link can ask to join and the event organizer will either allow or deny. You can only set the permission according to the 3 options in the screenshot above (Meet Safety Settings).

Refer to the link below:

- [Join a Meeting](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9303069?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cpersonal-account-users)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dan F, however i have a question `the users who are going to join this meeting` are not from my organization, they can anyone but they should be someone from my slack workspace.

I have updated my question for better clarity.

if they are from my slackspace then only they should be able to access the meeting that is why i need an authentication mechanism from slack

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Unfortunately there is no way you can do it since technically as a default anyone with the Google Meet link can ask to join and the event organizer will either allow or deny. You can only set the permission according to the 3 options in the screenshot in my posted answer above. I have edited my posted answer to clarify.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra hope this clarifies it. Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: As a general rule in StackOverflow, if your concern is solved please accept an answer which works best for you. This is to let other members from the community with the same concern as yours know that the issue resolved. [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If it does not exactly answer your question but somehow helped in any way, upvotes are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate and authenticate Slack with Google Calendar, maybe it can be done with API configuration. Here is the API link:

[Integrate the Google Calendar API with the Slack API](https://pipedream.com/apps/google-calendar/integrations/slack)